# How much time should take to count the frequency of 100K words in Java

Tags: java, file, hashmap, frequency

I have to read through a text file with roughly 100K words and create a HashMap with the frequency of each word. The code I have so far takes about 15-20 minutes to execute and I'm guessing I'm doing something horribly wrong. 
How much would the execution time for such task be?

This is the code I'm using

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordFrequencies = new HashMap<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        wordFrequencies.merge(scanner.next(), 1, (a, b) -> a + b);
    }
    return wordFrequencies;
```

Comment: Not really related, but you have potential problem if file will end with empty line. `hasNextLine` will return `true` but `next` will throw exception because there will be no token there. Use `hasNext()` in your loop condition.

Comment: Try changing the contents of your loop to just call scanner.next() (or scanner.hasNext()) and also increment a counter and then return the counter when you're done and see how long that takes (the counter is there to keep the inside of the loop from being optimized away. If it doesen't take long then try different logic for counting frequencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should take next-to-no-time. As in, if you're doing this just once, you should barely notice the time it takes. If it's taking 20 minutes, you're processing roughly 100 words per second, which is abysmal performance, even if your words are really long.

From the Javadoc of [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) (emphasis added):

> In general, each read request made of a Reader causes a corresponding read request to be made of the underlying character or byte stream. **It is therefore advisable to wrap a BufferedReader around** any Reader whose read() operations may be costly, such as **FileReaders** and InputStreamReaders.

Try wrapping the `FileReader` in a `BufferedReader`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt")));
```

Comment: Both Andy Turner 's and @Bill 's answers helped improved a lot my problem. Thanks